# jQuery Countdown that dont reset

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I'm using the jQuery countdown from Keith Wood (http://keith-wood.name) and I would like to know how I keep the counter going when someone refreshes the page. So every time someone enters the page he must see the countdown going

I'm a complete newbie with jQuery. I make use of the jquery.countdown.min.js file.

Here is the JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wthf9/2/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

            jQuery('#offline-countdown').countdown({

                until:'+1d, 1h, 3h, 3m, 1s',
                format: 'DHMS',
                labels: ['Years','Months','Weeks','Days','Hours','Minutes','Seconds']

            });
        });
```

Thanks a lot if someone can help me!

**UPDATE!**

You can find here the answer if someone need:

http://jsfiddle.net/wthf9/7/

Comment: You are going to have to persist the countdown timer between pageloads, so you are looking at a cookie or localStorage.

Comment: Agree with Mark, if you want individual counters for ever unique user. But what it sounds you are asking for is a time set to a specific date/hour which you will achieve by using a date in the 'until' field.

Comment: In this format: new Date(2010, 12-1, 25), instead of  '+1d, 1h, 3h, 3m, 1s'

Comment: @Mark, not necessarily. If the time is fixed, whenever a page reload occurs the new time is calculated and gives the appearance of the state persisting.

Comment: @dave but this ignores the offset of the users date/time making this a brittle solution.

Comment: @Mark how does it ignore the offset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will ensure that the countdown "persists" across page refreshes.

The reason this works w/o cookies or local storage is because the time is fixed, so when the page is refreshed a new time is calculated on the fly giving the appearance of state.

```
$(function(){
   var newYear = new Date(); 
   newYear = new Date(newYear.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 1); 
   $('#offline-countdown').countdown({until: newYear}); 
});
```

Here's an example of it in action. (Try refreshing the page with this fiddle)

http://jsfiddle.net/wthf9/6/

Sidenote: `$(function() { });` is the same thing as `$(document).ready(function() { });`

Comment: Ty a lot dave! this work perfect need a bit of time to set the good date but work perfect Thanks! :D

Comment: @Michele As I noted above this is going to use the user's local date/time so there are potential hijinks ahead.

Comment: @Mark, maybe that's what she wants. In the example of a new year countdown, that is exactly what you'd want.

Comment: Just work good :D no problem if have some hour difference i have just needed a simple countdown dont need to be perfect! thanks both guys i have update the jsfiddle so all can understand better! :D http://jsfiddle.net/wthf9/7/

Comment: very pretty :) @Michele