# My JQuery count down is not working perfectly,

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, countdown

I want to make a jQuery timer count down. It should have days, day, month, hours, seconds. I used this below code, but it is not working. When the browser is refreshed, the counter is restarting. Please help me to correct this code.

This is the jsFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/saifudazzlings/LfLdo381/

The js code:

```
var sec = 60;
var min = 100;
var hr = 24;
var updateTimer = function() {
    var timer = localStorage.getItem('timer') || 0;
    var timermin = localStorage.getItem('timermin') || 0;
    var timerhr = localStorage.getItem('timerhr') || 0;
    $("div#timermin").html(timermin);
    $("div#timerhr").html(timerhr);

    if (timer === 0) {
        $("div#timer").html("00");
    } else if (timer <= 1) {
        timer--;
        timermin--;
        localStorage.setItem('timermin', timermin);
        $("div#timermin").html(timermin);
        if (timermin < 1) {
            if (timerhr == 0) {
                localStorage.removeItem('timermin', timermin);
                $("div#timermin").html("00");
                localStorage.removeItem('timer', timer);
                $("div#timer").html("00");
                localStorage.removeItem('timerhr', timerhr);
                $("div#timerhr").html("00");
            } else {
                timerhr--;
                localStorage.setItem('timerhr', timerhr);
                $("div#timerhr").html(timerhr);
                localStorage.setItem('timermin', min);
                $("div#timermin").html(timermin);

            }
            //timerhr--;
            //localStorage.setItem('timerhr', timerhr);
            //$("div#timerhr").html(timerhr);
            //localStorage.setItem('timermin', min);
            //$("div#timermin").html(timermin);
        }

        localStorage.setItem('timer', sec);
        $("div#timer").html(timer);
    } else {
        timer--;
        localStorage.setItem('timer', timer);
        $("div#timer").html(timer);

        if (timermin == 0) {
            localStorage.removeItem('timer', timer);
            $("div#timer").html("00");
            $("div#countermessage").html("00");

        }
    }
};

$(function() {
    $("#start").click(function() {
        localStorage.setItem('timer', sec);

    });

    $("#start2").click(function() {
        localStorage.setItem('timermin', min);
        localStorage.setItem('timerhr', hr);
    });

    setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);

    $(window).load(function() {
        localStorage.setItem('timer', sec);
        localStorage.setItem('timermin', min);
        localStorage.setItem('timerhr', hr);
    });
});
```

Comment: Please share html code...

Comment: *"not working perfectly"* is a tad vague...  What's it doing/not doing?  What do you expect it to do/not do?  Can you at least format your code?

Comment: What do you mean by it is _"reloading when it is refreshing"_? Do you mean the whole page? Or the timer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a jquery count-down timer that doesn't restart on refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40245416/how-to-make-a-jquery-count-down-timer-that-doesnt-restart-on-refresh)

Comment: Sounds like it would be better if your timer counted down to an actual date. You could get the current date (server-side) and pass it to your timer along with the target date you wish it to countdown to.

Comment: *"I want to make a jQuery timer count down. It should have days, day, month, hours, seconds."* What a strange timer with two "days" and no "minutes".